# error with building a tree using mc2d

Tags: r

I am making a tree which will eventually turn into a set of arms with probabilities attached to going down each arm, with a value at the end of each arm.

This is the final arm of me tree (I am building it backwards).

```
require(mc2d)
ndvar(1000)

sderror_dfail<-(0.30-0.86)/1.96
alpha_dfail<-0.62*{{0.62*{1-0.62}/{sderror_dfail*sderror_dfail}}-1}
beta_dfail<-alpha_dfail*{{1-0.62}/0.62}

probs_d_if_fail<-mcstoc(rbetagen,type="V",shape1=alpha_dfail, shape2=beta_dfail, 
min=0, max=1)

lots1<-mcdata(1)
test<-lots1-probs_d_if_fail

probs1 <- mcstoc(rempiricalD, values=1:2, type="V", prob= c(probs_d_if_fail,test))
```

The next step is to build a branch of a tree as follows:

```
node1 <- mcprobtree(probs1, list("1"=mcdata(0), "2"=mcdata(1), type="V")
```

However the line probs1<- mcstoc(....) when I run it gives me the following error

```
Error in function (n, values, prob = NULL)  : 
Prob and values should be of same length or have the same number of columns.
```

I get the feeling it doesn't like me using mcstoc object as the prob=c(probs_d_if_fail,test) part of the equation, but am not sure how to work around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Timothy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rempiricalD` requires a a multivariate mcnode as `prob` argument. This is tricky.

Try:

```
require(mc2d)
ndvar(10000)

sderror_dfail<-(0.30-0.86)/1.96
alpha_dfail<-0.62*{{0.62*{1-0.62}/{sderror_dfail*sderror_dfail}}-1}
beta_dfail<-alpha_dfail*{{1-0.62}/0.62}

probs_d_if_fail<-mcstoc(rbetagen,type="V",shape1=alpha_dfail, shape2=beta_dfail, 
min=0, max=1)

lots1<-mcdata(1)
test<-lots1-probs_d_if_fail
probs <- mcdata(c(probs_d_if_fail,test),type="V",nvariates=2)
probs1 <- mcstoc(rempiricalD, values=1:2, type="V", prob= probs)

node1 <- mcprobtree(probs1, list("1"=mcdata(0), "2"=mcdata(1)), type="V")
node1
```

But the following code might be simpler if it fits your needs:

```
require(mc2d)
ndvar(10000)

sderror_dfail<-(0.30-0.86)/1.96
alpha_dfail<-0.62*{{0.62*{1-0.62}/{sderror_dfail*sderror_dfail}}-1}
beta_dfail<-alpha_dfail*{{1-0.62}/0.62}

probs_d_if_fail<-mcstoc(rbeta,type="V",shape1=alpha_dfail,
shape2=beta_dfail)

node1 <- mcstoc(rbern, type="V",prob = 1-probs_d_if_fail)
node1
```

Note that `rbern` will provide a 1 with probability (1-probs_d_if_fail), as you need if I understand well.

RP

Comment: Thanks, works well. I was needing it to put 1 with probability (probs_d_if_fail), but have changed my code to do that.
Cheers.